# AJAX post not working but I get a 200 OK

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I can't retrieve the post value on my PHP file.  Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="add_to_cart">
   <input class="product_id" name="product_id" value="989" type="hidden">
   <input class="cart_btn" type="submit" name="add" value="Προσθήκη στο καλάθι">
</div>
```

**AJAX request**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cart_btn").click(function(){
    var id=$(".product_id").val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/add_to_cart.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

**add_to_cart.php**

```
<?php


        $test = $_POST['id'];
        echo $test;

?>
```

I get the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: id in K:\Xampp

Comment: yes i know i changed it on purpose. still it is not working

Comment: var id=$(this).val(); it should be  var id=$(".product_id").val();

Comment: When i check the network status i can see the value...

Comment: You should really use English names for variables and IDs. It makes the code much more maintanable if someone that does not speak the language comes along.

Comment: Where do you get the error? JS console? You don't seem to be canceling the default submit action

Comment: @apokryfos That's a PHP notice.

Comment: yes it is a php. I cant retrieve the id...

Comment: My hunch is that you're not *sending* the id.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase that. Are you redirected to `add_to_cart.php` after you click the button (making the AJAX call absolutely pointless?)

Comment: No. Im opening it from the network console

Comment: This is crazy. I can see that my Post Data is id=989

Comment: This is even crazier because I cannot reproduce this on my local.

Comment: You can help me. Post your code from your local

Comment: It is working Great it was my mistake ithought is was not working. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `.cart-btn`, which is probably a `<a/>` or `<button/>`, will return `undefined` when calling `.val()` on it, since it's not an input.

Try hard-coding that string for a start instead; `var id = "testing purposes"`.

If that works, you can put the product id in a data attribute instead:

```
<a class="cart_btn" data-product-id="2">Add to cart</a>
```

.. and access it like this: `var id = $(this).data('product-id');`

Comment: What is not working? Hard-coding the ID value? Also, did you try making the data an object instead? `var dataString = {id: id};`

Comment: Now my id is undefined

Comment: The problem is in the variable declaration `var id = $(this).val()`. Did you try swapping that out with `var id = "foo";`?

Comment: Yes it is the same. I thing that my ajax request is ok. I dont have a form tag in my html though. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Nope, when using `$.ajax` a form shouldn't be necessary. Can you check the `network` tab to see what's being sent?

Comment: IN COPY RESPONSE i get the same result 989

Comment: So if you copy the response and get 989 out, it basically works?

Answer (score -1):

Try this simply using jquery $.post method

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cart_btn").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();   
      //var product_id=$(this).val(); // Button value "Προσθήκη στο καλάθι"
      var product_id = $('.product_id').val(); // Hiddent input value "989"
        $.post( "ajax/add_to_cart.php", { id: product_id}, function(resp){

        });
   })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You do realize that that is [exactly the same](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L833-L852)?

Comment: @Dencker there's a preventDefault on this one. Which is kind of important.

Comment: Ah, I only read "Try this simply using jquery $.post" - Sorry.

Comment: @Dencker Yes i know it is same $.ajax but jquery also provide more short method for use ajax $.get and $.post as our requirement why we use long method $.ajax.